# can not deploy process activiti

Tags: java, deployment, activiti

I am trying to implement the activiti example from [activiti user guide](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#_getting_started_10_minute_tutorial), but my process wasn't deployed. There is no errors, no anything.
My java code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ProcessEngine processEngine = null;
   ProcessEngineConfiguration processConfig= null;
   processConfig =  ProcessEngineConfiguration.createProcessEngineConfigurationFromResourceDefault();

   processEngine = processConfig.buildProcessEngine();
   //Get Activiti services
   RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
    RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
    
    //Deploy the process definition
    repositoryService.createDeployment()
        .addClasspathResource("diagrams/FinancialReportProcess.bpmn20.xml")
        .deploy();
        System.out.println("Your process should be deployed...");
    
    //Start a process instance
    runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("financialReport");
        System.out.println("Your process should be started...");

    
    // Get the first task
    TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
    List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("accountancy").list();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      System.out.println("Following task is available for accountancy group: " + task.getName());

      // claim it
      taskService.claim(task.getId(), "fozzie");
    }

    // Verify Fozzie can now retrieve the task
    tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee("fozzie").list();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      System.out.println("Task for fozzie: " + task.getName());

      // Complete the task
      taskService.complete(task.getId());
    }

    System.out.println("Number of tasks for fozzie: "
            + taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee("fozzie").count());

    // Retrieve and claim the second task
    tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("management").list();
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      System.out.println("Following task is available for management group: " + task.getName());
      taskService.claim(task.getId(), "kermit");
    }

    // Completing the second task ends the process
    for (Task task : tasks) {
      taskService.complete(task.getId());
    }
  }
```

and my FinancialReportProcess.bpmn20.xml code is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <definitions id="definitions"
  targetNamespace="http://activiti.org/bpmn20"
  xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn"
  xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">

<process id="financialReport" name="Monthly financial report reminder process">

  <startEvent id="theStart" />

  <sequenceFlow id='flow1' sourceRef='theStart' targetRef='writeReportTask' />

  <userTask id="writeReportTask" name="Write monthly financial report" >
    <documentation>
      Write monthly financial report for publication to shareholders.
    </documentation>
    <potentialOwner>
      <resourceAssignmentExpression>
        <formalExpression>accountancy</formalExpression>
      </resourceAssignmentExpression>
    </potentialOwner>
  </userTask>

  <sequenceFlow id='flow2' sourceRef='writeReportTask' targetRef='verifyReportTask' />

  <userTask id="verifyReportTask" name="Verify monthly financial report" >
    <documentation>
      Verify monthly financial report composed by the accountancy department.
      This financial report is going to be sent to all the company shareholders.
    </documentation>
    <potentialOwner>
      <resourceAssignmentExpression>
        <formalExpression>management</formalExpression>
      </resourceAssignmentExpression>
    </potentialOwner>
  </userTask>

  <sequenceFlow id='flow3' sourceRef='verifyReportTask' targetRef='theEnd' />

  <endEvent id="theEnd" />

</process>

</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should initialize your process engine like this,

ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration()
                .setDatabaseSchemaUpdate(ProcessEngineConfiguration.DB_SCHEMA_UPDATE_FALSE)
                .setJdbcUrl("your jdbc url")
                .setJdbcUsername("username")
                .setJdbcPassword("password")
                .setAsyncExecutorEnabled(true)
                .setAsyncExecutorActivate(false)
                .buildProcessEngine();

Comment: GJ dude, but how did you know? Have you got to tell me a tip, how can i understand these logical errors?

Comment: you are creating a process engine which does not have any configuration like database connection, username, password etc... Another way can be having activiti.cfg.xml file where you can specify the configuration of process engine. have a look at this http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#configuration

Comment: I never understood where to find this file. Should I created manually or I have to import it?

Comment: and if it was available, where should it be?

Comment: In your resources folder or in your project classpath